# To what extent are linguistics questions permitted?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

We've received a number of recent questions which seem to me to have a Linguistics slant.  Up to now, I'm the only one to have provided a vote to close.  Does this mean the community is on vacation, or that they think these questions should remain here?

- [How to render proper names having a hidden overtone in their semantic structure as it has essential meaning for prose fiction?](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/q/671/13)
- [Do Scandinavian languages have liaisons?](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/q/673/13)

And in a more general sense: To what extent, if any, do we want to allow questions about the linguistic characteristics of languages, rather than about techniques for learning these languages?

Comment: FWIW, I've asked a [meta question at Linguistics](http://meta.linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/1700/935) as well, inspired by this, but asking for perspectives from their side.

Answer (score 2):

I assure the community definitely isn't on vacation; I'm very much still here. I must've not stumbled over these questions previously, but now, I too have cast a close vote on both, as they both seem to related to the linguistic aspects of a specific languages.

As such, I think such questions are off-topic here, as they don't actually relate to any aspect of learning a language.

Answer (score 2):

Linguistics questions are permitted to the extent that they are about those domains in [**applied linguistics**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Applied_linguistics) that are related to **language learning**: first language acquisition, second language acquisition (which also covers the acquisition of foreign languages generally), language assessment, bilingualism, multilingualism, etc.

There may even be questions related to **cognitive linguistics** that are relevant to language learning, although I don't have any examples at the moment.

[**Comparative linguistics**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparative_linguistics) can also be relevant to this site; see e.g. [What metrics can be used to gauge language similarity?](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/7/what-metrics-can-be-used-to-gauge-language-similarity).